# EF7 Identity custom table name first seed

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a new clean asp.net 5 project (rc1-final), I just need to change default ef identity table name.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        // On event model creating
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Define table name
        builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("BackEnd_AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("BackEnd_AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("BackEnd_AspNetUserRoles");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("BackEnd_AspNetUserLogins");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("BackEnd_AspNetUserClaims");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("BackEnd_AspNetRoles");
    }
}
```

I get following error

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot use table 'BackEnd_AspNetUsers' in schema '' for entity 'ApplicationUser' since it is being used for another entity.

Comment: You can only map one entity to a table, the exception is pretty self-explanatory I think

Comment: Note how your first two mapping point to the same table 'BackEnd_AspNetUsers'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines here show you are trying to setup mappings for both the base identity classes and your application's inherited version of these classes;

```
builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("BackEnd_AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("BackEnd_AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
```

You don't need both, you should only have the inherited one specified - `ApplicationUser`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use   **`ForSqlServerToTable`**`("newtablename")`

```
builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ForSqlServerToTable("BackEnd_AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ForSqlServerToTable("BackEnd_AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
```